# Change character encoding for file read using OpenRead

Tags: import, character-encoding

I have a large bzipped file that I want to read using OpenRead on a pipe with UTF8 encoding.  Doing the following does not give me UTF-8 encoding.  My `$CharacterEncoding` is set to `"UTF8"`.

```
f = OpenRead["!bunzip2 -c " <> filename]
```

`OpenRead` does not have a `CharacterEncoding` option like `Import` does.  So the following works:

```
txt = Import["!bunzip2 -c " <> filename, "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"];
```

But `Import` forces me to load all the data before operating on it which I don't want.

**UPDATE1**:  For now I'm reading in the string as bytes and then converting to UTF8 manually

```
FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[s], "UTF8"]
```

I notice *Mathematica* UI has problems printing certain Unicode characters as others stackoverflowers have noticed.

Comment: `CharacterEncoding` is not supported for the low-level input streams which `OpenRead` works on.  It is not in the `Options`.

Answer (score 5):

As OP has figured it out, the correct method for reading strings encoded in UTF-8 or similar and which contain special/accented characters is to read in raw bytes and convert them using `FromCharacterCode`. That is exactly what `Import` does under the hood (which is spelunkable if one dares to venture into the ~13500 lines of code associated with `Import` or the ~16000 lines of the `Trace@Import[file, "Text"]` stack).

`Import` first opens a stream and reads in the contents as `Read[stream, Record, RecordSeparators -> {}]`, then processes the garbled string as:

```
 FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode["Ã¡rvÃ­ztÅ±rÅ tÃ¼kÃ¶rfÃºrÃ\.b3gÃ©p"], "UTF8"]
```

> ```
>  "árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép"
> ```

Let's set up a file that contains UTF-8-encoded accented characters:

```
file = "test.txt";
stream = OpenWrite[file, CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"];
WriteString[stream, "árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép"];
Close@stream;
```

`ReadList` fails, `Import` succeeds but is slow, `BinaryReadList` is fast:

```
ReadList[file, String]
Import[file, "Text"]
FromCharacterCode[BinaryReadList@file, "UTF8"]
```

> ```
> {"Ã¡rvÃ­ztÅ\[PlusMinus]rÅ tÃ¼kÃ\[Paragraph]rfÃºrÃ\.b3gÃ©p"}
> "árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép"
> "árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép"
> ```

Interestingly, the following encoding specification also works, though not included in `$CharacterEncodings` (internally, `Import` uses `"UTF-8"` instead of `"UTF8"` sometimes):

```
FromCharacterCode[BinaryReadList@file, "UTF-8"]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a guess, but a little exploration reveals a couple of things. First, if you look at the [examples](http://wolfram.com/xid/0j48jks6-ltfrry) for the `Method` option for `OpenRead` you will notice that one of the stream methods is `"File"`. This suggests you may be able to pass a `CharacterEncoding` to it, as follows:

```
strm = OpenRead["somefile", Method -> {"File", 
   CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"}]
```

which you can check by looking at its `Options`:

```
Options[strm]
(* 
{
 BinaryFormat -> False, 
 Method -> {"File", 
  BinaryFormat -> False, 
  CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"}
}
*)
```

So, it appears to have worked at least as far as the options are concerned. Now the "file" `"!bunzip2 -c " <> filename` is not a file, but is likely a `"Pipe"` as found by running

```
$InputStreamMethods
(* {"String", "HTTP", "WindowsTextFile", "GZIP", "Pipe", "File", "HTTP"} *)
```

So, I would try passing a `CharacterEncoding` in via the `Method` option.

Comment: Unfortunately adding `Method -> {"File", BinaryFormat -> False, CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"}` to OpenRead has no effect besides changing the result of Options[] call for the stream. Maybe this is a bug? I've put up my test file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1567217/test.txt).  There are some 2-byte UTF-8 characters there.